# How to upload directory to amazon S3 using servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-s3, directory, filepath

I am new to AWS and I have tried to upload a single file using servlet, it works fine but for a project I need to upload entire directory. 
There is one [C# solution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadDirDotNet.html), but Is there anything where I can get a fileDirectoy name from client side and upload that directory to S3 ?